Check if network is up before copying
I am running an nfs network under Ubuntu 22.04. I use cron/FreeFileSync to back up to a server but occasionally if the network is down for whatever reason the backup is written to /media/servername/backupdirectory in root. This did not matter to much with spinning disks but I am concerned that writing several thousand files to an ssd and then deleting them multiple times is going to impact on SSD life eventually. Is there a way to prevent the backup proceeding if the network is down ?

Instead of checking whether the network is up and running I would suggest checking that the target location is actually a mountpoint, using the mountpoint command.
Ex.
$ mountpoint /mnt/nfs/nas-01/public/
/mnt/nfs/nas-01/public/ is a mountpoint
$
$ sudo umount /mnt/nfs/nas-01/public
$ mountpoint /mnt/nfs/nas-01/public/
/mnt/nfs/nas-01/public/ is not a mountpoint

You can use the command's exit status to test whether it is safe to run the backup command:
if mountpoint -q /mnt/nfs/nas-01/public/; then
  run_backup
else
  echo 'target filesystem not mounted: backup aborted' >&2
  exit
fi

where run_backup is replaced by your actual FreeFileSync command(s).

Some bash-code to give an example:
# colors, setaf/setab  fg/bg
CALERT="$(tput setab 1)"
CERROR="$(tput setaf 9)"
CNORM="$(tput sgr0)"
COK="$(tput setaf 4)$(tput setab 2)"

net="$(ip r | sed -nre '/default/s/.*dev ([a-z0-9]+).*/\1/p')"
linkup="$(ip link show $net | grep ' UP ')"
if [ -z "$linkup" ] ; then
  echo -e "\n${CERROR} No network? $CNORM"
else
  echo -e "\n${COK}Network OK $CNORM $linkup"
fi


Trying to determine where ip belongs...
$ apt-file search '/ip' | grep -E '/ip$'
bash-completion: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ip
iproute2: /bin/ip
iproute2: /sbin/ip
netctl: /usr/lib/netctl/ip
pcp: /etc/pcp/pmlogconf/tools/ip
pcp: /var/lib/pcp/config/pmlogconf/tools/ip
vlan: /etc/network/if-up.d/ip

$ which ip
/usr/sbin/ip

$ ip --version
Option "-version" is unknown, try "ip -help".

$ ip --help
--- no version info ---

$ ls -l `which ip`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 mar 31  2024 /usr/sbin/ip -> /bin/ip

$ ls -l /bin/ip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 772856 mar 31  2024 /bin/ip


steeldriver's method is a better way to go about doing what you want to do, because it will make the script skip the backup and exit whenever the share is unmounted, as opposed to just when the network is down: the share could be unmounted for reasons other than the network being down, and you'll want to skip the backup and exit regardless of the specific reason.
But to answer the actual question: you could parse ip address to check if the interface connected to the network the share is hosted on has an IP address. Assuming the interface's name is eth0 :
if ip -4 -j address | jq -e --arg i eth0 '.[] | select(.ifname==$i)' >/dev/null; then
    printf 'Run backup\n'
else
    printf 'Exit\n'

    exit 255
fi

ip:

-4: list only interfaces with an IPv4 address
-j: output as JSON
address: list only interfaces with an address

jq:

-e: exit with status 0 only if the last outputted value was neither false nor null
--arg i eth0: inject a variable i with a value of eth0 in the script
.[] | select(.ifname==$i): print only objects containing a key ifname whose value is equal to the value of i

